# Is spring-data-redis 1.2.1 compatible with Redis 2.8.9?

Tags: redis

My Redis Server is 2.8.9 and I am using spring-data-redis version 1.2.1.RELEASE. Are both compatible?

Answer (score 0):

As per the http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/requirements.html

spring-data-redis version 1.2.1.RELEASE should be compatible with Redis Server is 2.8.9